# Can particle に be always interpreted as adverbial modifier marker?

Tags: grammar, adverbial

In English there are [12 cases of adverbial modifier](http://moluch.ru/conf/phil/archive/137/7518/).

1. Can all these 12 adverbial cases in English be expressed by Japanese particle に?
2. Are there other grammatical functions expressed by particle に?

Comment: There are so many cases to check and answer. At least the Japanese translation of the first one "On Monday nights it was closed." is "そこ（その店）は、月曜日に店を閉めていました。"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Q. Can all these 12 adverbial cases in English be expressed by Japanese particle に?

### A. Some, yes. Not all.

As Sonny365 TANAKA mentioned, に can be applied to some of them, but not all.

Also, there're sentences which can be understood, but not natural with に.

I don't remember Japanese grammar well, so instead of that, let me translate them into natural Japanese for me.

1. 月曜の夜**には**、そこは閉まってる。(に is okay, though)
2. 1週間ずっと、それは夜**に**踊ってた。(Difficult to translate all at once)
3. 踊り - クラブは the Rue de la Montagne Sainte Genevieven **で**開かれた。
4. 俺はビールを飲んだ。出入口に立ってストリートの涼しい風に吹かれ**ながら**。
5. 彼女はぱっちりとした目で見上げ、何気ない風に話そうとしていた。
6. 彼は前の本で**めちゃくちゃ**稼いで、まだ稼ぐつもりでいた。
7. 彼は何ヶ月も妻と別れようとしていたが、まだしていなかった。**なぜなら**彼女を拒むのは残酷すぎたから。彼女から離れていったのは、とても健康的なショックだった。
8. それを光らせてオフィスに飾りたいもんだな。
9. 彼女は僕の目をあの感じで見つめていた。そうだ、君を本当に目で見つめているのかどうかわからなくさせたあの感じだ。
10. 彼女は地球上の何にでもないように見えた。そして彼女は本当に、多くのことを恐れていた。
11. タクシーは丘を登った。明りのついた広場を通りすぎて。...
12. そのビールはおいしくなくて、口直しの**ために**よりクソなコニャックを飲んだ。

1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12 are straightforward. Each of them has a corresponding expression.

The problem with 5, 8, 9, 10, 11 is that they don't have the perfect Japanese translations.

**No.5** might be able to be separated into two sentences in Japanese.

**No.8** says about the result. In this case, I learned in school that we can use this template:

「A **して** B する」

Using this, No.8 is translated into like 「それを光ら **せて** オフィスに飾りたいもんだな」

**No.9** was difficult to translate. I feel like conditional adverbial modifier turns into just conjunctions both in English and Japanese. Separating an English sentence may be a good idea when you translate into Japanese.

**No.10** contains comparison. Both of *As if* and *As though* are translated into 「みたいに、感じに、ように、かのように」in Japanese. These words are quite similar and all sounds like *Like*. So,

"She pretended as if she was the girlfriend of him"
「彼女は彼の彼女**みたいに**ふるまってた」

"Your face is like a monster"
「お前の顔、怪物**みたい**だな」

See? Both translations contain「みたい」.

Btw, "I was like "What the heck are you doing!?"" is 「お前なにしてんの!? って感じだったよー」 in Japanese. 「感じ | みたいな」are really useful words. The same as I thought *Like* is useful.

I think the translation of **No.11** is the same as No.5. Just separate it.

### Q. Are there other grammatical functions expressed by particle に?

### A. Yes.

There're three にs in Japanese.

**に the 格助詞**
「机の上**に**ある。」

**に the 並列助詞**
「魚**に**肉**に**デザート**に**、全部おいしそうだなぁ。」

**に the 終助詞**
「そんなに急ぐこともないだろう**に**。」

This is all according to [this article](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AB).
格助詞 seems to be the one you mentioned in the first question.